# adding button on video background in html and css. Z-index not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

trying to add a  button on fullscreen video background in html and css. Z-index not functioning tried each element separately and they work. But they dont stack on top of each other. i might be missing an important link that i am unaware of. 
adding the html and css code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>homepage</title>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet2.css"/>
</head>
    <body>
    <video id ="videobg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" lopp="loop">
<source src="secret.3gp" > video not supported<video/>
</video>
<div id="button">
<img src= "button.png"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>

CSS FILE 

#button{
left: 490px;
  top: 560px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1
}
#videobg{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Full screen video?  Is the user clicking the maximize/fullscreen button on the html5 video?

Comment: Also, looks like you're missing a `;` after your `z-index:1`

Answer (score 0):

Try just wrapping the video in a div.  This worked for me: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smjmhkn9/25/).

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet2.css"/>
            <title>homepage</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="videowrap">
                <video id ="videobg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop>
                    <source src="secret.3gp" >
                </video>
            </div>
            <div id="button">
                <img src= "button.png"/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS FILE

```
#button{
left: 490px;
  top: 560px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1
}
#videobg{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}
```